# preact-router with default case not working as intended

Tags: preact, preact-router

I am new to `preact` and I am trying to develop a project with Preact-X.

I want my project to run with default URL with only one component.

for ex: `loaclhost:8080`, `localhost:8080/jobs`, `localhost:8080/?some-parameters`.

I have a component like below:

```
import { h } from 'preact'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router } from 'preact-router'
import Jobs from './jobs/index'

function App({ store }) {
    function handleRoute(e) {
        console.log(e.url)
    }

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router onChange={handleRoute}>
                <Jobs default />
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    )
}

export default App
```

I am not sure why it works only for `localhost:8080` but not other routes.

You can find the whole repo [here](https://github.com/pradeepb6/preactx-route-react-redux-boilerplate/tree/master/src)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set Webpack's [devServer.historyApiFallback](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback) option to true.

On [line 64](https://github.com/pradeepb6/preactx-route-react-redux-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L64) of your configuration:

```
devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  // etc
```

Comment: Thank you @json-miller for taking your time to answer :-)